# Unexpected result when filtering freqItemsets in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-mining

I'm following [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html) tutorial about association rules

```
val ar = new AssociationRules()
  .setMinConfidence(0.8)
val results = ar.run(freqItemsets)
```

I added `.filter(item => item.items.length == 1)` to `freqItemsets`, but nothing shows up, e ten though there are several rules of the form `item a => item b`.

Comment: Where did you add the filter? Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 3):

I ran the example of the site and I didn't get any problem, I got some items.

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth

val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://master/spark-sample-data/sample_fpgrowth.txt", 16)

val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))

val fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.2).setNumPartitions(16)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)

val individualItems = model.freqItemsets.filter(
  itemset => itemset.items.length == 1)

//If you print the number of items
println(individualItems.count())
// 8

individualItems.map(x => x.items).collect()
// Array(Array(z), Array(x), Array(r), Array(s), Array(t), Array(y),
//   Array(p), Array(q))
```